# How to select multiple dates in flutter

Tags: flutter, datepicker

I want to select multiple dates from date picker (not range). Actually in my app I have added a workshop that will be hosted on multiple days, like 1 June, 7 June, 9 June. So i want to add add multiple dates. Is there a option to select multiple dates in date picker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to refer [**`table_calendar`**](https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar) package and [**`daterangepicker`**](https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/daterangepicker/selections?_gl=1*ww8hjv*_ga*MTYyNDA5MTU0LjE2NTQwODU4MDA.*_ga_WC4JKKPHH0*MTY1NDA4NTc5Ny4xLjEuMTY1NDA4NTg2MS4w&_ga=2.209091483.869275408.1654085800-162409154.1654085800#multiple-selection) use [**`syncfusion_flutter_datepicker`**](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_datepicker) package for that hope its help to you.

Comment: I think 1st will do it. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If someone else is looking for this question it is best to use `showDateRangePicker()`

you can use it like this

```
    DateTimeRange? result = await showDateRangePicker(
      context: context,
      firstDate: DateTime(2022, 1, 1), // the earliest allowable
      lastDate: DateTime(2030, 12, 31), // the latest allowable
      currentDate: DateTime.now(),
      saveText: 'Done',
    );
```

[Reference flutter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDateRangePicker.html)

[Reference 2](https://www.kindacode.com/article/how-to-implement-a-date-range-picker-in-flutter/)

Comment: Greate, much interesting.

Answer (score 0):

**Use syncfusion_flutter_datepicker 20.4.42  plugin**

```
SfDateRangePicker(
         view: DateRangePickerView.month,
         monthViewSettings: DateRangePickerMonthViewSettings(firstDayOfWeek: 6),
         selectionMode: DateRangePickerSelectionMode.multiple,
         showActionButtons: true,
         onSubmit: ( val) {
         print(val);
         },
         onCancel: (){
         _datePickerController.selectedRanges = null;
         }
         ),
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Even though I know it is too late, the solution is

> initialSelectedDates

It requires a List of DateTimes.